# adding two fractions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add two fractions in python

if input 1/4 + 1/4, I am expecting 1/2 result

I built a fraction class with an `__add__` method for addition

```
from fractions import gcd

class fraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.num = numerator
        self.deno = denominator
    def __add__(self, other):
        self.sumOfn = self.num + other.num
        self.sumOfd = gcd(self.deno,other.deno)
        return(self.sumOfn, self.sumOfd)



print(fraction(1,4)+fraction(1,4))
```

However I am getting 2,4 as output, which is actually 1/2, just not simplified. How could I fix that problem ?

Comment: The general approach to simplifying fractions is to find the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of the numerator and denominator and then divide both of them by it.

Comment: The `fractions` module already has a [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) type.  All you need is `from fractions import Fraction` and then `print(Fraction(1,4)+Fraction(1,4))`.

Comment: @AnthonySottile it works I suggest you put the same answer below and I will select it as best answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general approach to simplifying fractions is to find the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of the numerator and denominator and then divide both of them by it

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by [@icodez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2555451/icodez)

```
from fractions import Fraction
print(Fraction(1,4)+Fraction(1,4))
```

Comment: Simple and precise

Comment: The addition in Fractions need to be defined. In this example fraction operations are done via floating point which means you are loosing precision
>>> x = 0.1

>>> x.as_integer_ratio()

>>> a = x.as_integer_ratio()[0]

>>> b = x.as_integer_ratio()[1]

>>> from fractions import Fraction

>>> f1 = Fraction(a,b)
>>> float(f1+f1+f1)
0.30000000000000004

Comment: Why converting into float?

Answer (score -1):

This works :

class fraction:

```
def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
    self.num = numerator
    self.deno = denominator

def __add__(self, other):
    self.sumOfn = self.num + other.num
    self.sumOfd = gcd(self.deno,other.deno)

    num=gcd(self.sumOfn,self.sumOfd)

    res_num=self.sumOfn/num
    res_den=self.sumOfd/num

    if res_num==res_den:print res_num
    else:print res_num,"/",res_den
```

(fraction(1,4)+fraction(1,4))