# Why doesn't sympy.simplify do arithmetic with fractions in python the way it is demonstrated in the documentation?

Tags: python-3.x, fractions, simplify

I would like to do arithmetic on fractions and have the results come out as reduced fractions. For example, I want 1/4 + 1/16 to come out as 5/16. And then I would like to use that result to do further computations. For example I'd like to be able to add 1 to the 5/16 and get 21/16.

I tried 2 approaches and neither was satisfactory.

The first approach was to use fraction.Fraction. Here I got the following

```
In [12]: from fractions import Fraction

In [13]: Fraction(1/4+1/16)
Out[13]: Fraction(5, 16)
```

Clearly Fractions knows what it's doing, but won't display the result as 5/16.

Then as suggested in

[adding two fractions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425285/adding-two-fractions-in-python)

I could get 5/16 by printing Fraction(1/4+1/16)  as in

---

```
In [187]: print(Fraction(1/4+1/16))
5/16
```

---

However this 5/16 is for display purposes only as it has no type

```
In [188]: type(print(Fraction(1/4+1/16)))
5/16
Out[188]: NoneType
```

and cannot be used in further calculations

```
In [190]: print(Fraction(1/4+1/16)) + 1
5/16
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-190-87b52dc30510> in <module>()
----> 1 print(Fraction(1/4+1/16)) + 1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

So this approach appears to be a dead end.

My second approach was to use sympy.simplify

On the documentation page for simplify,

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#simplify

there is a SymPy Live Shell that can be used to experiment with simplify.

When I enter simplify(1/4+1/16) into the Live Shell I get

```
 5
 -
 16
```

which is exactly what I want.

Moreover when I run simplify(1/4+1/16) + 1 in the Live Shell I get

```
21
--
16
```

So simplify seems to do what I want.

However when I run simplify(1/4+1/16) in ipython with python 3.6, I get

```
In [139]: simplify(1/4+1/16)
Out[139]: 0.312500000000000
```

So I get the right answer, but I don't get the fractional output that the Live Shell gave me.

Why does the ipython behavior differ from the SymPy Live Shell behavior? And is there any other way to get what I want?

Comment: You get NoneType because you're looking at the type *of the return value of `print`*, and since `print` doesn't return anything, it's type is NoneType. In the next snippet, you're trying to add 1 to the return value of `print`...

Comment: Printing the Fraction object gives you the string output of `5/16` because the class defines `__str__` for string conversion. You can use the object by saving it to a variable...