# Python-properly adding fractions

Tags: python

I would like to do some calculation with fractions, keeping all the numbers as fractions and never converting to decimals.

For example 1/2+1/4=3/4. We can do this in Python for example by using a function from the fractions class: Fraction(1/2+1/4) or Fraction(1/2)+Fraction(1/4), if we want.

However I can't get Python to give me the correct fraction for 1/2+1/3 because 1/3 is a non-terminating decimal. Fraction(1/2+1/3) doesn't work, nor does Fraction(Fraction(1/2)+Fraction(1/3)).

***EDIT: The reason why I used Fraction(1/2) instead of Fraction(1,2) is because, in my code I know that I'm working only with fractions but I won't know the numerator and denominator of a fraction just the fraction itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181262/9624798

Comment: Whats wrong with `Fraction(1, 2) + Fraction(1, 3)`?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled on how you know your fraction "but don't know the numerator or the denominator". Could you elaborate on that ?

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can.

```
>> from fractions import Fraction
>> Fraction(1, 2) + Fraction(1, 3)
Fraction(5, 6)
```

---

Your **notation** seems to be the problem. Notice that:

```
>>> Fraction(1/3) == Fraction(1, 3)
False
```

while

```
>>> Fraction(1/2) == Fraction(1, 2)
True
```

As a result:

```
>>> Fraction(1/2) + Fraction(1/3)
Fraction(15011998757901653, 18014398509481984)  # almost 5/6 but not quite
```

That happens because when you type `Fraction(1/3)` the `1/3` is calculated first and then passed to `Fraction`. On the contrary, `Fraction(1, 3)` simply creates a fraction using `1` as the numerator and `3` as the denominator.

Comment: Fraction(1,3) == 1/3 still returns False.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fraction function in this manner.

```
from fractions import Fraction
f = Fraction(1,2) + Fraction(1,3)
print (f)
```

Output: `Fraction(5,6)`